# String comparison doesn't work in while loop

Tags: java, loops, input, while-loop, do-while

Noob Java question: Why won't this Do While loop accept the user input? When I use a different variation (such as int for the answer), it works. But when I look for a string, it never accepts the string and escapes the loop.

This works:

```
int value = 0;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    value = scanner.nextInt();
}
while(value != 5);
System.out.println("Do while loop has ended.");
```

This doesn't work:

```
String pass;
String word = "word";
do {
    System.out.println("Enter password: ");
    pass = scanner.nextLine();
}
while(pass != word);
System.out.println("Password accepted.");
```

Thanks

Comment: you should be using string.equals() method. the way you are comparing is their memory location  not the literal string.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
while(pass != word);
```

to this:

```
while(!pass.equals(word));
```

You were comparing the references when you used `!=`, not the actual content of the strings. Since they did not point to the same `String`, your loop would always exit on the first run.

Comment: Ah, did not see that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"==" compares addresses in memory so if you enter the word which will be the same, the reference you have stored will point to different object.